# Django Admin Search DateTime Field without milliseconds

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-admin

I have Django instance with postgres. By default with this configuration DateTimeFields in Django are saved with milliseconds.

```
# models.py
class LogModel(models.Model):
    date_logged = models.DateTimeField(
        "Logged",
        auto_now_add=True
    )
# admin.py
class LogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('date_logged',)
    search_fields = ('date_logged')
```

I'd like to search by admin panel in *date_logged* field without including milliseconds or searching by this field while it has custom datetime format. Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: I would try playing with https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_search_results

Answer (score 0):

Use date format to remove the miliseconds of the date before searching

```
from .models import LogModel
import datetime

myDate = datetime.now()
formatedDate = myDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

LogModel.objects.filter(date_logged=myDate)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

If you having trouble getting the format of your date by user input or from your frontend, try to create one date object first and then make the search

```
# datetime(year, month, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[, tzinfo]]]]])
import datetime

formatedDate = datetime.datetime(date_from_user.year, date_from_user.month...)
# OR
formatedDate = date_from_user.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: I know that I make it by Django ORM, but I'd like to searching by Django Admin search box defined by search_fields. By default, by searching this field, milliseconds are also included.

Comment: I guess you will have to override it... because its a native widget, never tried it before, if you get any good response let me know